# Is there an Mouse Event to unselect an element from a TableView Javafx?

Tags: java

I'm creating a Tournament application. I've got 2 Listview and 1 TableView , I need to get a function that unselect the match when I click on a random place in my application.

Comment: Hi Cesar welcome to Stackoverflow, can you provide what you have tried already? By the way give a quick look to the How to Ask page https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Hi T.V - I tried to create a variable numSelectMatch = -1; if this variable is between 0 and the size of the list, it selects a element in my tableView and if this variable is equal to -1 or higher than list.size() it should unselect but it didn,'t work for me.

Comment: please edit your question with your actual code in order for other people to check and give you some help.